# Extremely slow SELECT statement with WHERE on a FK field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014-express

I have this query below, and it's extremely slow.  It takes almost 2 minutes for run to return 3,008 records out of a table with 99 million records.  The first query where it gets "Article" data is super fast, less than 1 second and always returns 1 record.  It's the second query that's the problem.  I don't really want to JOIN these queries.  The first one is so quick, and (in my real query) I'm setting more than just @ArticleID for further use.

The query execution plan says it has 75% for it on a clustered key lookup on IX_Name, which didn't make sense to me because I'm not even doing anything with name fields here. Furthermore, Id and ArticleID are both indexes on ArticleAuthor, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can't do much with IX_Name being the clustered index...my boss created this table and said to do that.

```
DECLARE @DOI VARCHAR(72) = '10.1140/EPJC/S10052-012-1993-2'

DECLARE @ArticleID VARCHAR(12) 

SELECT 
    @ArticleID = A.Id
FROM
    Article A 
LEFT JOIN 
    JournalName JN WITH (NOLOCK) ON JN.Id = A.JournalId 
WHERE 
    A.DOI = @DOI

PRINT 'GOT ARTICLE DATA ' + format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff')

SELECT 
    AA.Id 
FROM 
    [ArticleWarehouseTemp]..ArticleAuthor AA WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    AA.ArticleID = @ArticleID 

PRINT 'GOT ARTICLEAUTHOR DATA ' + format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff')
```

Please help! This is driving me insane. I've attached the table structure and indexes here too.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ArticleAuthor]
(
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ArticleId] [int] NOT NULL,
[FullName] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
[FirstInitial] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
[OrcId] [varchar](36) NULL,
[IsSequenceFirst] [bit] NULL,
[SequenceIndex] [smallint] NULL,
[CreatedDate] [smalldatetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ArticleAuthor_CreatedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
[UpdatedDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[Affiliations] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [ArticleAuthorFileGroup] TEXTIMAGE_ON [ArticleAuthorFileGroup]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ArticleAuthor] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ArticleId] 
   FOREIGN KEY([ArticleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Article] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ArticleAuthor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ArticleId]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ID] 
ON [dbo].[ArticleAuthor] ([Id] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ArticleID] 
ON [dbo].[ArticleAuthor] ([ArticleId] ASC)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Name] 
ON [dbo].[ArticleAuthor] ([LastName] ASC, [FirstName] ASC, [FirstInitial] ASC)
```

Comment: Note: The actual query execution plan says there's 75% on a clustered key lookup.  Object = IX_Name and Output = ArticleAuthor.Id field.  I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: Key Lookup means your query needs more columns that are present in the index - so for each value found in the index, SQL Server has to go back to the main table and get the data pages - extremely inefficient. What **index** was used in the step *before* the key lookup? Maybe you can just add one or two columns as `INCLUDE(....)` columns to your index and remedy this situation

Comment: IX_Name is a clustered index, so I apparently can't add an INCLUDE to that one.  However, I'm thinking I can add Id as an INCLUDE on the IX_ArticleID one since I'm looking up on ArticleID and selecting ID?  The query execution plan shows 25% on an "Index Seek" on this IX_ArticleID object, but I don't see ID reference anywhere in the popup.  Super confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to keep the current clustered index as is, you can do the following:

1.

Make sure that you are using correct types:

```
DECLARE @ArticleID VARCHAR(12)
```

should be

```
DECLARE @ArticleID int;
```

to match the type of the column `ArticleId` in the `ArticleAuthor` table.

2.

To make sure that index `IX_ArticleID` is used efficiently, to make it a covering index, `INCLUDE` the column `Id` to it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ArticleID] 
ON [dbo].[ArticleAuthor] ([ArticleId] ASC)
INCLUDE(Id);
```

3.

If you have a very skewed distribution of data, i.e. a number of rows per `ArticleId` varies greatly for different articles. Say, if one article has 2 rows and another article has million rows, then you'd better add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the query and make sure that statistics and/or index(es) are kept up to date.

Comment: Thanks.  These two suggestions, especially the INCLUDE on this index sped it up from about 2 minutes down to 27-40 seconds.  Not the best, but greatly improved! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring DECLARE @ArticleID VARCHAR(12) while its int in your table [dbo].[ArticleAuthor][ArticleId] [int] NOT NULL,

Try to make them same datatype to ensure faster response.

Comment: Thank you...that certainly seems to help, but it's still taking a full minute and 20 seconds to run.

Comment: It's because you don't have an index on the column you are searching for (ArticleID)

Comment: @LoztInSpace I do have one (IX_ArticleID).  See original post.  Also under original post, my note about IX_Name.

Comment: So it does.  Sorry.  Why you see reference to IX_NAME is that non clustered indexes have to have a copy of the clustered index key so they can find it.  The DB will use your index then find by name, middle, surname + a hideen uniquifier where they are not unique.  The fact you've got no PK is odd - typically that's the key you'd use.  I don't know why it's taking so long but that's why you're seeing access to the name index.

Comment: Having said I don't know, I'd say the speed issue is because of the "interesting" choice of clustered index.  On top of the ArticleID index search you're then effectively doing 3000 individual lookups back to the main table on a pretty substantial index (64 nvarchars) + uniqueifier.  That gives you 0.027 seconds to find each row. I'd seriously look at changing the CI to be the PK.